# Verificar se URL contém número

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de verificar se a URL atual contém números após o #.

Não preciso saber se contém um número específico ou uma quantidade de números, só preciso saber se existe um número qualquer depois de #.

EX:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com#**123** *TRUE*

https://pt.stackoverflow.com# *FALSE*

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Só uma dúvida, "um número qualquer" seria se existe qualquer número ou deve ser exatamente um número válido? Exemplo: `#123abc` contém um número qualquer, isso seria válido? Ou deve ser especificamente um número, como `#123` e `#123a` seria inválido?

Comment: @fernandosavio seria somente números!

Comment: MFT, você poderia esclarecer sua pergunta nos comentários da resposta do sam ??

Comment: @fernandosavio claro, postei lá

Comment: Valeu, agora fica bem documentado caso alguém caia aqui no futuro. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Capture o hash com `location.hash` e verifique se tem número com `.test()` usando uma expressão regular `\d` (número de 0 a 9):

```
var hash = location.hash;
if(/\d/.test(hash)){
   console.log("tem número");
}else{
   console.log("não tem número");
}
```

Pode usar uma função para isso também:

```
function verHash(i){
   if(/\d/.test(i)) return true;
   return false;
}

verHash(location.hash);
```

Então você pode atribuir o valor da função a uma variável se quiser e verificar:

```
var tem_numero = verHash(location.hash);

if(tem_numero){
   console.log("tem número");
}else{
   console.log("não tem número");
}
```

Ou pode verificar direto no `if` sem declarar uma variável, se desejar:

```
if(verHash(location.hash)){
   console.log("tem número");
}else{
   console.log("não tem número");
}
```

> Para verificar se o hash contem **apenas números** (ex., #123, #1
>   etc.) troque a expressão regular de `\d` para `^#\d+$`.

Comment: Sam, o AP esclareceu um pouco mais no comentário da pergunta. Como a sua resposta é a aceita e a mais completa pensei que você poderia alterar o código para contemplar o que ele disse agora que está mais claro o que ele precisa.

Comment: Cara, tava pensando, sua resposta permite `#123abc` como válido e não bate com o que o AP quer. Seria só usar a regex `/^#\d+$/` ao invés de `/\d/` que ficaria correto.

Comment: Quando questionei se é para testar se a hash contém números ou se é para testar se tem somente números, o AP [respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339777/verificar-se-url-cont%c3%a9m-n%c3%bamero/339783?noredirect=1#comment685938_339777) que seria apenas números. Por isso meu comentário

Comment: Também achei ambíguo, por isso perguntei pra ele. Vou pedir para ele esclarecer isso e se não esclarecer, paciência. :D

Comment: Cara, analisando melhor, realmente vc tem razão, ficou meio ambíguo. Vou adicionar na resposta a verificação apenas com números.

Comment: Na realidade eu diria que é indiferente pq são só duas opções, ou vai ter números após o # ou vai ficar vazio.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o `location.hash` para fazer essa verificação

```
if( ! isNaN( location.hash.substr(1) *1 ) )
{
    /// é um numero
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo bem simples:

```
var valor1 = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com#";
var valor2 = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com#123i";

var verifica1 = valor1.substr(valor1.indexOf("#") + 1);
var verifica2 = valor2.substr(valor2.indexOf("#") + 1);

var encontrou1 = verifica1.match(/\d+/g);
var encontrou2 = verifica2.match(/\d+/g);

alert(encontrou1 != null);
alert(encontrou2 != null);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lagsybt/